# Graphviz, distance between table node and edge

Tags: graphviz

How can I remove the space between the border of the table and the edge ?
The node seems to have a margin outside of the table.

The definition of the graph in dot:

```
strict digraph {

  rankdir=RL;
  node [shape=none, style=filled, fillcolor=aliceblue, fontname=verdana];

  Model [shape=none, label=<<table border="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr><td border="1" bgcolor="lightblue">Model</td></tr>
    <tr><td border="1" align="left">Name</td></tr>
    <tr><td border="1" align="left">Description</td></tr>
    <tr><td border="1" align="left">Universe</td></tr>
  </table>>];

  Universe [shape=none, label=<<table border="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr><td border="1" bgcolor="lightblue">Universe</td></tr>
    <tr><td border="1" align="left">Name</td></tr>
    <tr><td border="1" align="left">Description</td></tr>
  </table>>];

  Model -> Universe

}
```

The resulting png is:

[image]

Using graphviz version 2.38.0.

Any comment much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Employ the `margin` keyword:

```
node [shape=none, style=filled, fillcolor=aliceblue, fontname=verdana, margin=0];
```

That'll reduce that aliceblue area around the tables to nothing and make the arrows really connect the tables.

[image]

Comment: Works. Must have overlooked this in the doc. Thanks.